# Emacs plugin for storing written code as template

Tags: emacs

For example, standard libraries in C/C++ are used very often, and it's very inefficient to go to the web browser, search for the code example how to use a library component, copy the source code and modify to suit your need; a few month later, you need to use that library component again but forgot how to use it, and you have to repeat the whole process again!

This process is not very productive for me because after we learn something the first time, we do not need to fully study the same thing again; just part of it can help us recall how to use it. I want my written code or example code copied from the web site to be stored for later reference and modification.

Emacs macro is an option, but I think you have to type the whole source code to make a desired template. What if I found a well written code, and I want to store that code segment for future reference? Macro won't be productive because I have to type the whole thing.

Is there Emacs plugin for doing this?

Comment: look at yasnippet: https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet. Looks like macro, but more flexible.

Comment: I am using yasnippet. It is certainly good but yasnippet only has predefined macro for language constructs. What I want to do is storing my written code as template, so I can insert it back later when I need, so I reduce the repetitive actions during my coding session.

Comment: I don't see the problem. yasnippet can do just that. Simply create a snippet that contains your code template.

Comment: Ok I think I will try to write a templatet for yasnippet. It's not really code template though, as it will contain fully written code in some existing application.

Comment: You could write a [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) source, so you can easily select and insert any of your snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend snippets for the task that you described.

Snippets are meant to be repeated often. You can't have a lot of them.

What you need is something that you use rarely, but can have a lot of.
I'm using `org-mode` for this task. With `org-mode` you can:

1. Organize your knowledge by language/library etc.
2. Include small code snippets directly via babel.
3. Attach any number of files to any heading.

This way you get the overview/description via the headings,
and the actual code via code blocks / attachments.

Another advantage is that you can easily grep your org-file / your attachments.
Other advantages are timestamps, TODOs and all kinds of export that `org-mode` provides.

### UPD

Just to give you a sample of what it can do (open in in emacs, otherwise it looks ugly):
https://gist.github.com/abo-abo/6040382/raw/1be55e30a9ed8d81cc1b2b752b7d498d05e72978/hyper.org

Comment: Sounds like the tool I need. I wanted to learn org-mode for sometimes, but leave it later for other things. Now I have a compelling reason. Thanks.

Comment: Nice example. This is exactly what I am looking for. However, when I click on the entries in the table, it said "No match-create this as a new heading". Maybe something is wrong with my org-mode setup? If the link works, will clicking on it insert code template?

Comment: I already filed an emacs bug for this.
You need to eval (require 'ord-id).

Comment: And the link jumps you to the code. However, since it's org-mode/babel, 
you can open any snippet in its native-mode with (C-c ') as well as
run the code in-place with (C-c C-c). It might not work straight out of
the box for clojure and python though.

Comment: It worked after I eval (require 'ord-id). (C-c ') and (C-c C-c) is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a list on the [EmacsWiki: Templates](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryTemplates).

Personally I know [TempoMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TempoMode) and [Yasnippets](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet). I prefer Yasnippets. The snippets are very easy to write and have support for variable fields which you enter on snippet insertion.

Answer (score 1):

This should provide a command inserting the last item of current kill-ring.

```
(defun my-code ()
  (interactive "*")
  (insert "(defun ")
  (save-excursion (insert (concat "()
  (interactive \"*\")
  (insert \"" (car kill-ring) "\"))"))))
```

Remains to specify the name of the command when done - and installing it.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used [Else-Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElseMode) to do just that sort of thing, especially when the project I was working on had a very rigid and long, required function header comments.

Comment: Thanks. Also not quite what I am looking for, but it would be useful for other use cases I am also having.

Answer (score 1):

You can look to [SRecode](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/srecode.shtml) from CEDET package. Besides standard templates, like yasnippet, etc., it also provides support for content-aware templating, like some templates could be expanded only inside the classes, some only as top-level declaration, etc.

Comment: After a year I finally understand how useful SRecode can be. Using Org is ok, it's just that I cannot have a quick way to insert like SRecode does.